# Matching URLs in text except for pre existing <a href=''...> links

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

```
var URLREGETX1 = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim;
```

that captures the protocol and url. It works well but I would like to make sure that it does not catch foo links.

I try to fiddle with `(?!href=\")` without much success.

https://regex101.com/r/fE7pY9/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this work using a [negative Look Behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
(?<!RegExpThatShouldNotBeAPrefix)RegExpToMatch
```

According to regex101 this is however not supported by Javascript. But you should test this in the field.

I made it work by switching to python.

https://regex101.com/r/tU1fS3/1

Comment: Indeed its not valid with JS. I will try something else.